# Parsing messages using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am connecting to a service via web-sockets that sends messages for some events that occur.

I receive messages in the following format :

```
scope("unique_id_01").spot.occupied=false
```

How can I parse this message to extract the value ( in this case false) ?

Note :
The service API docs mention that these messages are **eval-able JavaScript messages**, and not JSON format.

The service also sends another message as format is :

```
scope("scope_abcd-01").zone.event({"id":"abcd-02","occupied":true,"timestamp":"2015-01-13T09:13:55.644Z", ..otherData});
```

The text in the event(..) field is a valid json string. To parse the above event I was using the following code :

```
var scope = function (scopeKey) {
    var result = {
        zone: {
            event: function (jsonMsg) {
                console.log("Scope : " + scopeKey + " id : " + jsonMsg.id);
                // use the json
            }
        }
    };
    return result;
};

eval(message received from websocket);
```

Before passing it to eval I was also validating it to be valid and genuine response.

How do I parse both the messages that I receive ?

Comment: These server messages are strings?

Comment: @Abovestand : Yes, these are strings

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex to extract the relevant values:

```
var messageFromServer = 'scope("unique_id_01").spot.occupied=false';

var matches = /^scope\("(.*)"\)\.spot\.occupied=(.*)$/.exec(messageFromServer);
if(matches){    
    console.log(matches[1]); //'unique_id_01'
    console.log(matches[2]); //'false'   
}
```

Use capturing groups to target the dynamic content. All matches here will still be strings - JSON.parse the matches you know to contain valid JSON.

Comment: I was thinking of using Regex for parsing, but the docs of the service mention the messages to be eval-able, hence was thinking it would be better not to use Regex. Any suggestion/views?

Comment: Does the service provide function definitions for you?